# How to upload photo captured by camera to Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Okay i am actually working on an android app that is like instagram and i need to know how can i upload the image the user selects from his galley and upload it to parse
I tried reading parse documntions but I acctually didnt understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have class [ParseFile](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html) exactly for that. ParseFile's constructor takes ByteOutputStream as an argument. So all you need to do is to compress your Bitmap file to ByteOutputStream. For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
new ParseFile("Name", bos.toByteArray());
```